# CSS - Multiple vs Single class on an element

Tags: css

Is there any performance gain in using single css class vs multiples on an element?

Ex:-

```
<div class="single-class"></div>
```

vs

```
<div class="no-padding no-margin some-class some-other-class"></div>
```

Comment: @Pekka - post that as an answer and I'd +1 it.

Comment: Oh, and another quick tip: Don't do `"no-padding"`, do `"noPadding"`. With most text editors, selecting words that contain a dash is a pain.

Comment: Yes, there is a performance gain. Will you *ever* notice it? Nope.

Comment: @Tomalak: Don't blame your tools. I think hyphens fit better to the "look" of CSS which uses them for properties.

Comment: @RoToRa: I don't blame my tools. I'm thinking practical.

Comment: @Tomalak, CSS ids and classes are commonly hyphenated, just like the CSS rules themselves. For consistency with other languages, CSS probably should have used camelCase, but it didn't.

Comment: ummm... css uses whatever naming convention you want for classes and ids. You can even use stars, hearts, and smilies. You can even use punctuation if you escape it.

Comment: I agree that using hyphens is becoming quite the standard with JavaScript and CSS frameworks. Camel casing is not prevalent and is quickly becoming unconventional.

Comment: CSS actually uses hyphens in this selector: `E[lang|="en"] Matches any E element whose "lang" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en". ` This can be applied to any attribute including classes.

Comment: @Eli: You can't use hyphens in javascript freely. For instance, function names cannot contain hyphens.

Comment: I know this, I am talking about JavaScript libraries creating CSS classes, not using them as actual code.

Comment: @Eli: Class names can be read as case-insensitive in IE quirks mode, which would be one good reason we typically don't use camelCasing as a standard, although hopefully we don't end up in quirks mode!

Comment: @Madmartigan I understand and totally agree. Our convention is lowercase hyphenated class names for these very reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have an even moderately complex stylesheet and know what you're doing, using multiple classes has the benefit of taking full advantage of the cascade, which in the end most likely means that your css files will be smaller as you won't be duplicating code. So, in this sense, it actually has a positive impact on performance (dependent on the complexity of your css).

I'm trying to imagine what the jQuery UI stylesheet would look like if it used a one-class-per-element approach. I imagine it would double in size.

Of course like everyone said, the impact is so small you won't notice. Continue your use of multiple classes and embrace the cascade!

---

FWIW, I really don't like class names like `no-padding`, `float-left` and `ui-corner-all`. Though they make sense to the css author, a semantic approach combined with multiple elements per declaration (to avoid duplicating rules) is almost always preferred. Using the first method, your css will make no sense if you decide that `no-padding` actually needs 1px padding, and that `a.classname.float-left` actually needs to float right.

Comment: On the other hand, if you add two or more classes instead of one to a large number (hundreds / thousands) of HTML elements, it may noticeable increase the file size of the document.

Answer (score 12):

Technically, **yes** fewer classes mean less data transfer for HTML. As far as CSS is concerned, each element needs to be checked against each rule, so fewer classes may mean less matching depending on the rules you have written.

The difference is so small that it's not easily noticeable. You may notice the performance difference if you're populating a page with tens of thousands of elements, but that would be a poor design choice anyway.

One concern I have is with the example you've provided. Your classes `no-padding`, `no-margin` are descriptive of *styles* which are a bad idea. If all your `some-class` elements also have the `no-margin` class, then `margin: 0` should be part of the `some-class` rule.

Don't add classes for styles, add styles for classes.

Answer (score 10):

The basic rule applies in CSS  like in other languages: Don't worry about optimization on this level unless you run into serious actual performance problems, or have tens of thousands of elements. Use what is more readable instead.

There may be differences - using CSS selectors in a sane way is usually extremely un-optimal from a performance standpoint. But compared to other factors, any difference is going to be minuscule.

Comment: +1 for "tens of thousands", I'd written the same quantity when your answer popped up.