# Apply style to multiple selectors or use multiple classes. Which has better performance?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SASS but actually my question applies also to plain old CSS.
So I have this class:

```
.some-icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64, someBase64String');
}
```

So, now I have to use this icon at several places. I also need to write some additional css to place it correctly at the different places where it should appear. Since I don't want to duplicate this huge base64 string I'wonder which approach to use.

Either use `SASS`'s extend syntax:

```
.use-case-a{
    @extend .some-icon;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    ...
}
```

The compiled css would look like this:

```
 .some-icon, .use-case-a {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64, someBase64String');
}

.use-case-a{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    ...
}
```

Or should I just write:

```
 .some-icon {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64, someBase64String');
}

.use-case-a{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    ...
}
```

And then apply both classes `some-icon` and `use-case-a` on it?

I read that the first approach can drain performance:
https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/12

But I also read that applying multiple classes hurt performance, too.

What is the recommended practice here?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: For the better performance of what? The Sass compiler, the server, the network, the browser...?

Comment: Yes, the rendering speed. Well, yes I could benchmark it but I just wonder if there is already a best practice advice out there :)

Comment: Did you even read the link you provided?  The guy's problem was that he ended up with a selector that was *4000* characters long.  You're worrying about micro optimizations here.

Comment: Well, say you go for either of one approaches for the whole site and you have hundreds of elements and then it turns out that either one of those approaches is the better one that would make a difference.

Comment: SO is not a benchmarking service.

Comment: it's funny that you absolutely can never know how people react. Could have also been that some clever guys posted: "Hey, it's a good practice to go for approach one unless you don't overuse it with hundreds of selectors" Or the other way around. You just can never know in advance. If I expected this question not to be answered I wouldn't have asked. Humans...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too had this question and after some research I found a post about [CSS Rendering Speed - Grouping Selectors vs Properties](http://forrst.com/posts/CSS_Rendering_Speed_Grouping_Selectors_vs_Prop-T4S) on Forrst.

While the author compares the difference between grouping selectors vs properties in the CSS, I wanted to know if it were faster to apply styles using multiple classes on the elements… so [I made a test](http://forrst.com/posts/CSS_Rendering_Speed_Grouping_Selectors_vs_Prop-T4S#comment-568005), [the author ran it](http://forrst.com/posts/CSS_Rendering_Speed_Grouping_Selectors_vs_Prop-T4S#comment-568136), turns out it is faster to use multiple classes in your html:

```
                                   1k      10k
Grouping Selectors layout time   ~12ms   ~110ms
Grouping Properties layout time  ~12ms   ~117ms
Object Oriented CSS layout time  ~11ms   ~112ms

Grouping Selectors DOM ready     ~50ms   ~405ms
Grouping Properties DOM ready    ~64ms   ~640ms
Object Oriented CSS DOM ready    ~47ms   ~349ms

Grouping Selectors file size      55kb    563kb
Grouping Properties file size     93kb    943kb
Object Oriented CSS file size     64kb    633kb
```

Additionally when you use more classes in the markup your code will be more readable, predictable, maintainable, scaleable, etc. When you read the following code, you know that this item is an icon and that it's also a checkmark icon.

```
<div class="icon icon-checkmark"></div>
```

This code also allows for easy selection of all "icon" elements with JavaScript.

Overloading the styles on a class will limit the ways in which you can use the class.

All said, since the actual browser render time delta is negligible, optimization at this level should be focused on saving developer time.

The answers here are quite sound too: [CSS - Multiple vs Single class on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568718/css-multiple-vs-single-class-on-an-element)